# Ethers JS Contract BalanceOf Returns Zero

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js

I am trying to query the amount of arbitrary tokens in my wallet through ethers.js. I need a way to query the amount of tokens other than ETH, and trying to use contract.balanceOf for this purpose.  However, contract.balanceOf returns 0.  Provider.getBalance works great for ETH, but not for other tokens.

Any other way to query the wallet balance for arbitrary tokens would suit my purpose.

This code returns the correct amount of tokens:

```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY!)
const signer = wallet.connect(provider)
var balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address)
console.log(wallet.address, balance.toString())
```

However, this returns 0 for the same address.  The provider is the same, and the contract is correctly resolving the `.name()`, which I did not provide, so the contract constructor is connecting to the RPC node.

```
var abi = // copied from the contract online
// THe address below 0xD76b5c2a23ef78368d8E34288B5b65D616B746aE should be eth on mainnet
// I also tried 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2 "wrapped eth" below.  Same result.
const tokenContractAddress = toChecksumAddress('0xD76b5c2a23ef78368d8E34288B5b65D616B746aE');  
const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, abi, provider);
console.log(await contract.name())
balance = await contract.balanceOf(wallet.address);
console.log("****", wallet.address, contract.address, balance.toString())
```

TIA!

Comment: Can you share the value of `wallet.address` and to which network is your provider connected? Without these inputs, the issue is not reproducible.